# How can I perform code inspection on generated code in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I want to run the "Analyze -> Inspect Code" task on some generated code and see if there are unused methods ("unused declaration" warnings).

I tried to create a custom "scope" called "With Generated" and explicitly include the paths to the generated directory and the regular source tree. It shows that there are 51 files (including both my regular project files and the generated files). I believe it is processing this directory correctly (I assume the regular inspector would ignore the generated directory).

[image]

I removed the `@Generated` annotation from the generated java files, was not sure if this was preventing some analysis.

I manually added a few declarations like this to the generated file AND to a file in my source tree to make sure there are unused declarations that the inspector should find. I am not 100% sure that the generated methods (created from a third party library) would be considered unused (I don't explicitly call them in my code, but perhaps the analyzer determined they are reachable purely inside the generated code...). So, I put in methods which I know are never used to make absolutely sure there should be something found if the files are processed.

```
   public int foobar() {
      return 1;
   }
```

I then ran the inspect code command and choose the custom scope.

[image]

It does find unused declarations in the regular source tree.

[image]

But, it does not find unused declarations in the generated files, even those I have added manually.

Any ideas how I can inspect generated source code?

If it matters, I'm using the https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/ project to generate code from a schema and query as per their instructions. An example of an Android project would be here: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/tree/master/apollo-sample/src/main/graphql/com/apollographql/apollo/sample